# My discord.js help command doesn't exactly work

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

First things first, my help command does work but not in the way I would like it to work.

My first issue is that the commands are being sent in separate messages which is kind of annoying when you have a lot of commands.

My second issue is that when the message is sent in an embed, it shows up like this:

- Command
- Description
- Usage
- Undefined

I tried multiple ways to get rid of 'Undefined'.

My code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async(bot, message, args, con) => {
   fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
     if(err) console.error(err);

    let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
    if(jsfiles.length <= 0) {
        console.log("No commands to load!");
        return;
    }

    var namelist = "";
    var desclist = "";
    var usage = "";

    let result = jsfiles((f, i) => {
        let props = require(`./${f}`);
        namelist = props.help.name;
        desclist = props.help.description;
        usage = props.help.usage;

        // send help text
        let helpembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setTitle("Commands")
        .setFooter("Please report any bugs to Vati#1662")
        .setColor("RANDOM")
        .addField(`**${namelist}** \n${desclist} \n${usage}`)  
        message.author.sendEmbed(helpembed);
    });

   })
  }
    module.exports.help = {
    name: "help",
    description: "shows all commands",
    usage: "help"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use [`RichEmbed.addField()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=addField) it expects at least two arguments: the title of the field and its value.

```
.addField(`**${namelist}** \n${desclist} \n${usage}`) // this has only the title argument
```

Try putting the three "sections" in three different fields.

```
.addField("Name:", namelist, true) // the 'true' means that they're inline fileds
.addField("Usage:", usage, true) // they will try to fit on the same line
.addField("Description:", desclist) // if there's no third argument, the default is 'false'
```

The commands are sent in different messages because you're running the whole code for every command, and not only adding the fields for every command. If you don't want to spend time on all this stuff, you can use the `discord.js-commando` library: it's a framework that deals with the commands and also handles errors, incomplete commands, and a lot of other stuff. If you want to check it out, you can find the docs [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/commando/master/general/welcome).